# AWS DMS not migrating text columns from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

We're using DMS to migrate columns from a postgres RDS database and it only seems to be bringing across non text columns (integer, timestamp etc all working). However, when it sees a text column, we're getting nothing across from it.

Is there a reason for that, or some setting we need to change in our json (we're using CFT to build the job) that enables text columns to be transferred across?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to LOB setting in you DMS migration task. Data type `TEXT` is defined as LOB, so you have to be sure to check "Full LOB mode" - in full LOB mode AWS DMS migrates all LOBs from source to target regardless of size. It is slower, but it is guaranteed that all data types will be migrated.

[image: dms-lob]

Details in official documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.LOBSupport.html

Comment: The only supported transformation for columns that are mapped to BLOB/CLOB data types is to drop the column on the target. TEXT is mapped to NCLOB, [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.Limitation), [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html)